# Razor Pages DateTime Input Badly Sized

Tags: html, css, razor, razor-pages

I'm using Razor Pages and Asp.Net Core 2.2 with bootstrap 4.3.1. There's no custom CSS in the site. I literaly just created it by select file\new project in Visual Studio 2019

I have the following in my cshtml:

```
<form sp-page="./Index" method="get">
            <h5 class="card-title">Select Criteria</h5>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input asp-for="@Model.PageFilter.SearchFields.SearchFromDate" />
                        <input asp-for="@Model.PageFilter.SearchFields.SearchFromDateState" />
                    </div>
```

This is rendered in the browser as follows:

[image: bad datetime image]

I'd like to fix the following:

1. reduce width of the datetime input box.

   2. have seconds displayed in same weight font as the rest of the text.
   3. have the checkboxes for the datetime input display adjacent to the input boxes.

I've created a jsfiddle for this at: https://jsfiddle.net/BizTalkers/12m38bs0/1/

Could anyone please advise how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a max-width to the datetime input box should fix issues 1 and 3. I can't see issue 2 in my browser.

```
<input type="datetime-local" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SearchFromDate field is required." id="PageFilter_SearchFields_SearchFromDate" name="PageFilter.SearchFields.SearchFromDate" value="2019-05-17T16:54:03" style="max-width:180px">
```